# Counterexample for minimal DFA proof

Tags: combinatorics, formal-languages, automata, automated-theorem-proving

I'm struggling with a following task: Let $A = (Q, Σ, δ, q_{0}, F)$ be a `DFA`, in which every state is `attainable` (attainable state meaning that there exists a word that after reading that word, the automata will end up in said state). Is it possible to `ALWAYS` modify `F` in such way that the automata will be `minimal`?

So basically we have to think if it is always possible to modify `F` in an automata such that the automata will be `minimal` after that modification.

I know, that if we have a DFA with `N` states, then we have $2^N$ options to choose `F` from.
We have to find a counterexample DFA in which for every `F` picked there will be an option to further minimize the DFA.

I can't find a counterexample for that, could you help me with this task or maybe somehow narrow it down to some examples?

THANKS!

Comment: "We have to find a counterexample DFA in which for every F picked there will be an option to further minimize the DFA." Are you trying to show a contradiction for "It is possible to ALWAYS modify F in such way that the automata will be minimal"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am trying to find a DFA and prove by contradiction that this is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Method: Let's assume there are no un-reachable nodes. Then DFA minimization works on the assumption that there are equivalent, non-distinguishable nodes. Lets say there are two equivalent nodes, then one can always set one of the equivalent nodes to be in F and the other to not be in F, and thus distinguish them.

But what if there are more than 2 equivalent nodes? In such cases, even after changing F, some 2 nodes may remain non-distinguishable. Concretely consider the following example:

[image: Counterexample DFA]

In this case, the DFA accepts all words of size 2 or more. Can we find some subset of accepting states for which this is the minimal DFA? $C_0,C_1$ must be distinguished, so one must be accepting and the other not. Similarly, $D_0,D_1$ must be distinguished, so one must be accepting and the other not. But then, the accepting states, say $C_0,D_1$ can be merged and so can $C_1,D_0$ as they are non-distinguishable. So we cannot find any subsets of accepting states for which this is minimal.

Comment: I get the point, this is a cool proof, but I can't find a way to illustrate a DFA with 3 equivalent, non-unreachable nodes. Could you maybe show me an example of said DFA, that proves the point? Thanks!

Comment: ok i've amended my answer to provide example of more than 2 non-distinguishable states. See if this helps.

Comment: Okay, but I don't think that covers our problem though. We have to show that for every chosen subset of accepting states (there is 128 possibilities in your DFA above) our DFA will not be minimal. Yours example only shows that there is one such possibility

Comment: My question is: why does this prove that we CANNOT find ANY subsets of accepting states for which this is minimal?

Comment: the rest of the states can do anything, it doesn't matter.. so we're down to 16 possibilities for the four states under consideration. $C_0$ and $C_1$ have to be distinct as do $D_0$ and $D_1$, so we're down to 4 possibilities. these four all have (at least) two states which can be merged (as in the last line of the answer). So in all 128 cases, the DFA is not minimal.

Comment: Hmmm, but there is nothing in a way to pick S, A and B as accepting states, because accepting states influence what is being accepted by our automata.

Comment: What I was saying was irrespective of what S, A and B are, one can merge states to make a smaller DFA. See here for the details: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nVGR_468R23R4axoONaulUHhrFgOfc3H/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a counterexample. Consider the automaton $(Q, A, i, \cdot)$ where $Q = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 0\}$, $A = \{a, b, c\}$, $i = 1$ and the transitions given by $1 \cdot a = 2$, $1 \cdot b = 3$, $1 \cdot c = 4$, and, for each letter $x$, $2 \cdot x = 2$, $3 \cdot x = 3$, $4 \cdot x = 4$, $0 \cdot x = 0$ and all other missing transitions are of the form $q \cdot x = 0$.

I let you verify that two states from the set $\{2, 3, 4\}$ are necessarily equivalent.

Comment: I don't quite get it, could you explain it in some other way? 

https://imgur.com/a/KZ7Ujue - this is my drawing of said automata, I don't see how this proves the point that there is a way to minimize the automata after we have thought of every possible `F` (final state).